# How can I extract the title from an encrypted PDF in PHP?

Tags: php, linux, pdf, encryption

How can I extract the title from an encrypted (write protected, not password protected) PDF file using PHP on Linux? Usage of external libraries or binaries are OK. Zen_PDF did not work (`Exception: Encrypted document modification is not supported`) nor did libextract (`title="filename of pdf.pdf"`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using *nix, have you tried [XPDF](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/about.html)?

There is a blog post [here](http://davidwalsh.name/read-pdf-doc-file-php) about how someone has used it for a customer of their's - whether it will be of any help I'm unsure.

**EDIT:** There seems to be some code [here](http://community.livejournal.com/php/295413.html) that could help - a simple class that reads a PDF into plaintext. Unsure if it supports decryption.

**EDIT2:** There are also a number of resources in PHP documentation that may help you. [Click.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdf.php)

**EDIT3: [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) and [FPDI](http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/) may also help. Probably your best bet after some research.**