# Edit forms in encrypted PDF

Tags: php, pdf

I currently have the need of editing the forms which are inside a PDF.

Unfortunately, theses PDF are from the Government, so I don't have the password...

Is their a way of doing this in PHP?

Thank you.

Comment: related [How can I extract the title from an encrypted PDF in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455260/how-can-i-extract-the-title-from-an-encrypted-pdf-in-php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You need the password to unlock the PDF. If it's an older version of pdf, the encryption is probably weak and the password can be bruteforced by various apps, but recent PDF specifications use AES encryption and you're not likely to ever discover what the password is.

PHP cannot magically decrypt the PDF just because it's PHP, just as you can't fly even though you chugged a can of Red Bull.